# Javascript for loop check condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to create a function that will generate a random number between 0 to 9 which is not in the array.

My code so far:

```
 var myArr = [0,2,3,4];

  console.log("Arr: " + myArr);


  function newNum(){
     console.log("test");

     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       var n = myArr.includes(i)
       // I want to return n if it's not present in the array
     }
     return n;
  }

newNum()
```

I want to return only 1 number. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @karthick but how do I check if the number is present in the array? I want to generate a number that is not in the array.

Comment: Yeah sorry didnt read the question properly

Comment: Well `includes` returns boolean, so you need to do something like `if(!myArr.includes(i)) return i` that's all you need in `for` loop, if it gets outside, there is no possible num between 0-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```js
const invalidValues = [0,2,3,4];

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const getValidRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  while(true) {
    let temp = getRandomInt(min,max)
      if(!invalidValues.includes(temp)) {
        return temp;
      }
  }
}

console.log(getValidRandomInt(0,10))
```

Comment: a very costly way to generate random number if the distribution is only from 0 -9 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArr = [0,2,3,4];
  function newNum(){
     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       if (!myArr.includes(i)) {
            return i;
       }
     }
     // return -1 if all numbers present in array..
     return -1;
  }

newNum();
```

Comment: This appears to only be a partial solution as it does not show how to generate a random number between 0 and 9

Answer (score 0):

Generate the number within the range by using `Math.random()` then loop and check whether the number generated is in the array or not, if not in the array return the number:

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max, arr) {
  arr = new Set(arr);
  while(true){
      let val =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      if(!arr.has(val)){ return val;}
    }
}
console.log(getRandomArbitrary(0, 10, [4,3,2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

Use `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` to get a number within a range.

You can wrap it with `Math.floor` to round down to an integer, or alternatively use a bitwise OR ( `|` ) for small numbers.

```
function newNum(n_arr) {
 let r = () => Math.random()*9 | 0,
 n = r();
 while(n_arr.includes(n)) {
   n = r();
 }
 return n;
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
var myArr = [0,2,3,4];

  function newNum(n_arr){
     let r = () => Math.random()*9 | 0,
     n = r();
     while(n_arr.includes(n)) {
       n = r();
     }
     return n;
  }

let result =  newNum(myArr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr= [0,2,5];
function randomNumber(myArr, n){
    n ? n : 1;
    var num = Math.random() * n;
    if(myArr.indexOf( num ) !==-1 ) {
        return randomNumber( myArr, n );
    }
    return num;
}
randomNumber(myArr, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the first number missing in the array, from your code above, you could just check if every value of `i` exists in the array and the moment that value doesn't exist, return it.

```
 var myArr = [0,2,3,4]; // original array

  function newNum(){

     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // loop through i from 0-9

       if (myArr.indexOf(i) === -1){ // check for the first missing number
        return i; //return it
       }
     }
  }

newNum()
```